# adding a condition to SP2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-activity

```
If wfstatus equals contractingoffice
   update currentitem
   then email someabcperson
ElseIf wfstatus equals pending in abc office
   then email somexyzperson
```

This is the current situation and I need to check if the wfstatus is pending and then if it is > 7 days or >15 days then email to somexyzperson reminding them to take action.

I calculated the number of days and then wrote an if condition to check if it is > 7 days then email somexyzperson but it looks like it doesn't work in that way.....

Could you kindly suggest to me how to check it and then send the email to the concerned persons?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a pending date more than 7 days or more than 15 days, you need to add an action that does a calculation. Assuming that the item is pending as soon as the workflow kicks off, your logic should look something like this:

```
Add 7 days to Current Item:Created (Output to: Variable: MoreThan7Days) //Add Time to Date
If wfstatus equals contractingoffice
   update currentitem
   then email someabcperson
ElseIf wfstatus equals pending in abc office
AND If Today greaterthanorequalto MoreThan7Days //Another Condition
   then email somexyzperson
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the scenario is ...the request will be from one office to other like wise there are 5 offices. so created "find days between xyzofficeapproveddate and today(OUTPUT to variable time)" and then the elseif statement as mentioned in ur answer. hope it works...will let u know once i receive the email.